# Is the space $\mathcal C([0,1])$ endowed with the sup norm homeomorphic to $\mathcal C([0,1])$ endowed with the integral norm?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the space $\mathcal C([0,1])$ of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R$. A norm which is natural to use in this space is the sup norm: $\|f\|_\infty=\sup|f|$; another one is the integral norm: $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f|$.

> Are $\bigl(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_\infty\bigr)$ and $\bigl(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_1\bigr)$ homeomorphic?

My guess is that they are not, but I am unable to prove it. It is clear that these metrics are not equivalent. And, of course, since $\bigl(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_\infty\bigr)$ is a complete metric space, whereas $\bigl(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_1\bigr)$ isn't, there is no bijection $f\colon\bigl(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_\infty\bigr)\longrightarrow\bigl(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_1\bigr)$ such that both $f$ and its inverse are uniformly continuous, but this doesn't prove the impossibility of the existence of a homeomorphism.

Comment: Your guess is right, according to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256623/is-a-normed-space-which-is-homeomorphic-to-a-banach-space-complete/256628.

Comment: Try to find a sequence of elements that converges in one norm but doesn't converge in the other.

Comment: @HansEngler That's really easy (just take $f_n(x)=x^n$). And then what? That only proves that those two norms do not induce that same topology. How do you deduce from that that those two spaces are not homeomorphic?

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you. That surely answers my question.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3653264/42969 looks related. (From the question: *“Actually, I want to prove that $(C([0, 1]), d_1)$ and $(C([0, 1]), d_\infty)$ are not homeomorphic.”*

Comment: Duplicate of  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1738631/42969 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we embed $(C(X),\|\cdot\|_1)$ into its Banach space completion $E$, then **if** $C(X)$ were a $G_\delta$ in $E$ then any $f \in E\setminus C(X)$ would contradict Baire's theorem for $E$ as $f + C(X)$ and $C(X)$ are disjoint dense $G_\delta$'s in $E$. So in fact $E=C(X)$. (An old argument by Mazur).

Conclusion: $(C(X),\|\cdot\|_1)$ is not topologically complete (aka Čech-complete). So it cannot be homeomorphic to $(C(X),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, which is.

The [Kadec-Anderson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Kadec_theorem) says that if $X$ is a completely metrisable, separable locally convex TVS, then $X \simeq \Bbb R^\omega \simeq \ell_2$, topologically. So the non-completeness is the obstacle.